# How do I calculate the length of an x/y coordinate in Python?

Tags: python, computer-science

I'm constructing a program where the user clicks two points in the graphics window and the length of x and y must be shown. I've creating a clone and multiplying it by itself, but no luck. Any ideas? Thanks!

Edit:
My program is supposed to create a 'money bin' based off the users data and 2 point clicks in the graphics window. I need help figuring out how to get the 'length in x direction' after the user clicks 2 points on the graphics window.

-Here's the example inputs-
Enter shape of money bin:

1 cube/prism

2 cylinder

3 cone

4 pyramid

Shape: 4

Enter height of money bin: 96.5

Enter cost per cubic foot to build: 2.75

After clicking on the window, click the mouse at two points in the window to determine the money bin base

point 1 coordinates: 16.5258215962 45.7202505219

point 2 coordinates: 60.2190923318 13.4029227557

**Length in x direction: 43.6932707355 feet**

**Length in y direction: 32.3173277662 feet**

Volume: 45420.9336744 cubic feet

Cost to build money bin rounded to nearest dollar: 124908

Press  to quit

Comment: Which GUI toolkit are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by the 'length' of a coordinate? You've asked a bunch of related questions, and you haven't marked any answers for the previous ones.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information if you want to receive a useful answer.

Comment: Just FWIW, your 10-digits after the decimal point precision might be just a bit excessive -- you're specifying the size to about 1/10th the diameter of a single carbon atom!

Comment: the permeating stench of homework

Answer (score 5):

To get the absolute difference in the x coordinates use this formula:

```
dx = math.abs(x2 - x1)
```

Similarly for the y-coordinates:

```
dy = math.abs(y2 - y1)
```

On a related note, the formula for the distance between two points in two dimensions is:

```
dist = math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)
```

Comment: If this is the part he needs an explanation for, he shouldn't be going anywhere near GUI tools.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to calculate the distance between the two points? If so, you just use the Pythagorean theorem: √((y<sub>1</sub>-y<sub>2</sub>)<sup>2</sup>+(x<sub>1</sub>-x<sub>2</sub>)<sup>2</sup>).